# Implement right-clicking context menu using PopupControlExtender?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, contextmenu, popupcontrolextender

Is it possible to implement a context menu which appears when users perform a right-click on an item of interest using the PopupControlExtender?

From investigations so far, it seems like the PopupControlExtender only works with left-clicks or the other choices are to write your own control or implement the entire solution in jQuery.

If it is possible to do a right-click with the PopupControlExtender, may I get some code examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a hidden button on the form for the `PopupControlExtender`, then capture the right click and call document.getElementById('bla').click();

**JS:**

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            //alert('Left mouse button pressed');
            break;
        case 2:
            //alert('Middle mouse button pressed');
            break;
        case 3:
            document.getElementById('bla').click();  
            break;
        default:
            //alert('You have a strange mouse');
    }
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<asp:button id="bla" runat="sever" style="display:none"/>
.....PopupControlExtender code...etc
```